# How to structure multipart MIME to get IsFileDisposition to return true (.NET Core 2+)

Tags: asp.net-core, .net-core

I'm looking to implement some upload code using MultiPartReader and reading through sections in .NET Core.  I've seen a few examples that use IsFileDisposition() extension method and then cast to a file disposition to do the read.

I wanted to implement this strategy as well however I cannot figure out how to setup my client so that IsFileDisposition() returns true in the web api when I invoke my POST.

I've tried specifying a Content-Disposition of inline and attachment, specifying file name, no file name and everything else I could think of.

I also tried looking in github to see if I could stumble across Microsoft's open source version of this extension method so I could check it out, but can't find it.

Can anyone explain what this method actually checks for so I understand how to form my request?

Thanks!

Comment: The source code you are looking for is [here](https://github.com/aspnet/HttpAbstractions/blob/d142d58eb43626961117136c51993d51dfb7371d/src/Microsoft.Net.Http.Headers/ContentDispositionHeaderValueIdentityExtensions.cs#L19)

Comment: @SimplyGed you may want to add this as an answer so that people can vote and accept.

Comment: I don't want to put a link as the answer as it doesn't really answer the real question i.e. 'how to structure multipart mime', but does help the OP find the code that might provide him with an answer

Answer (score 0):

@SimplyGed - Thanks for the link, this is perfect.

Looks like my Content-Disposition header would need to look like this:

Content-Disposition: form-data; filename="filename.jpg"